# Use column information from MySQL table to type cast PHP data

Tags: php, mysql, casting, pdo, sqldatatypes

I have a few questions regarding safe data storage using PHP and MySQL.

First, I am using PDO and prepared statements before querying or saving any data to the database, specifically the wrapper created by Digg.

It recommends type casting all data before sending it to the prepared statement.

1. Is this necessary? And if so...
2. Is there a way that I can retrieve the column information for a specific table, build a "filter" of sorts that auto type-casts data according to the table's field information, before actually sending it to the field?

For example, suppose I have a table called players, with these columns:

1. id - int(11)
2. handle - varchar(100)
3. country - char(2)
4. team_id - int(11)

in PHP, before I save or update a player, assuming it's good practice to typecast data before saving it, then is there a function that will automatically map MySQL data types to PHP data types?

That way I could do something like settype($my_var, $data_type_from_matching_table_field).

Or should I just create a class with a bunch of switch cases?

Comment: Yes I've heard of it, I'm not a fan. Most values within PHP auto typecasts, meaning string "1" is internally handled as int 1. Second PDO has several methods of binding values to the prepared statement object, and these method all support the type you wish to add, e.g. PDO::PARAM_STR, PDO::PARAM_INT, etc. Strictly spoken, yes it's a good habit ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. In most cases, it isn't necessary.  There are a few edge cases where I have found it necessary: converting between MySQL date/datetime/timestamp and PHP DateTimes, converting between MySQL sets and PHP arrays, and converting objects with __toString to actual strings for the benefit of MySQL.  However, all of those are only necessary if you choose to use those slightly unusual data types on the PHP side.
2. It's possible, but the only way I know of is to parse the output of a "SHOW COLUMNS" or "SHOW FIELDS" query, and use that data in a long switch statement, as you mention.  I would suggest doing this just to handle the few special cases where your favorite data type doesn't agree with MySQL, and not bothering with the many cases where PHP's built-in type conversions will handle things correctly.